# When queue start then given verification link doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, queue, user-registration, email-verification

I want to send verification link when user registration. i am able to send verification link and it work properly when use php script like

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerificationMail($user));
```

and it send link like ( 
     http://127.0.0.1:8000/author-registration-verification-done/FQCi4KowFKrbj5xR5glg3WZhIrXL03zo8xnQ3M9P/5
)
when click this link user account activate with successfully.

but when use queue like

```
Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new VerificationMail($user));
```

it also a send link like ( http://localhost/author-registration-verification-done/ITw7Ezz9MX6hAl7iDzArshupA6eqyAmWeAyzECdr/3 )

**why send the the different link using send and queue**

this time this link doesn't work it shows an error.

[image: an error has occured]

Comment: In your first link you use port 8000 which is missing in your second example. Is this intended?

Comment: there no change in other file. only the change is send to queue

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.
only the the change in .env file.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

to

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```